# I have used enum in my code and it is crashing

Tags: c++, enums

I am using enum in the below code and using operator overloading but it is crashing. Could anyone explain why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

enum E{M, T= 3, W, Th, F, Sa, Su};

E operator+(const E &a, const E &b){
    unsigned int ea = a, eb = b;
    unsigned int ec = (a+b)%7;
    return E(ec);

}
int main(){
    E a = M, b = F;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    E day = a+b;
    //cout<<int(day)<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your exact message on crash? I see your problem, but I want to see if I could help you figure it out yourself. [ask]

Comment: The solution is simple: enable compiler warnings and never ignore them.

Comment: What do you want `ea` and `eb` for?

Comment: I think you intended to write `(ea + eb) % 7` and slipped.

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
E operator+(const E &a, const E &b){
```

This defines the `+` operator for two objects who are instances of class `E`.

```
unsigned int ec = (a+b)%7;
```

Both `a` and `b` are instances of class `E`, therefore the `+` operation will be done by calling your `operator+` overload.

Except that this is your `operator+` overload in the first place. So, this will end up calling the `operator+` again, in perpetuity, resulting in infinite recursion and a crash.

That's the reason why the shown code is crashing.